# Swift: Need guidance if this is a good approach on making nested UIView in VC

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

[image: Refernce]

Hi so right now I'm making some sort of camera app with some basic button like turn on flash, enable grid, etc.

The cameraViewController manages the view. And it has the UIView for previewing what to capture, and at the bottom, a UIView for the buttons, and shutter button.

Right now, this is how I approach it.
ShutterButtonUIView inside CameraEditorUIView, and CameraEditorUIView inside CameraViewController.

And my editor buttons (flash, grid, filters, etc) is of their own class. And I insert it into my view like so. That way, I promote separation of concern and my class won't be cluttered by all the many buttons.

```
let editorButtons = ActionButtonFactory.shared.editorButtons
for button in editorButtons {
   // Insert to CameraEditorUIView
}
```

And example of one of my editor button class

```
class FilterAction: UIButton {

    private let filter = ["paintbrush.fill"]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setImage(getIcon(), for: .normal)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc private func filterTapped() {
        TapticHelper.shared.lightTaptic()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .presentFilterListVC, object: nil) //Not sure if this is a good approach 
    }

    private func getIcon() -> UIImage {
        return IconHelper.shared.getIconImage(iconName: filter[0])
    }

}
```

This makes my line of code very neat and small, good. But is it a good approach? I can't do any view controller functions such as presenting any alert, instantiate another VC, and such from the UIView.

So let's say After pressing the shutter button I want to go to imageDetailVC, My approach is to use NotificationCenter observer pattern.

I'm not sure if this is a good approach or not. Or should I put everything under CameraViewController?

Also, another reason I have doubt on this approach is when I need to disable the rule of third grid for example, I need to make it a static so that my other UIView can access it.

ie: A button from another class

Comment: It's generally not a good practice to use notifications to call functions and pass data between views and/or controllers.  An issue with notifications is the decouple related views and makes the code much hard to follow and debug, especially if someone else were to work on the project down the road as there is no clear path for how data gets from view X to controller A.  You'd be much better off with a protocol delegate design pattern, [this article goes into more depth](https://thenucleargeeks.com/2019/09/25/swift-delegates-and-protocols/).

Comment: While what you have might work, I think you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need custom buttons and classes for the editor buttons. If I were you, I would just add a couple regular UIButtons on storyboard where you want them to be, connect them with IBOutlets, and in viewDidLoad set up how you want the buttons to look. Then create IBActions for each button. Creating custom classes are really beneficial when you have an item that will repeat a bunch of times across your app. Here, I would assume "filterButton" is only needed on 1 or 2 view controllers...

Comment: @purebreadd Ah i see. I was thinking because if I was to have 10 buttons, It would clutter my view controllers. So if it was separated into their own class It would be a breeze and each class has their own onTapAction.

Comment: One option could be to make a collectionview with 10 cells, each cell having a button.  Create an enum for buttonType and pass that into each cell.When you configure the cell, set up the title/image for each button based on enum type. Then have a switch statement for the cell's button action based on the enum type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, But I've figured that instead of using UIView, I used UIViewController. And add them as a child VC. That way, I can still access the parent without coupling with notifications and make it harder.

So if I was to instantiate a new VC, I just used self.parent.